Oracle database 23ai: Error ORA-02264 occurs, but I can neither find a constraint with the specified name nor drop one
I am using Oracle database 23ai, free version, along with the PL/SQL developper of Allround Automations. I am getting the error ORA-02264 and though I understand its meaning (an already active constraint with same name was found where assigning the same name to two constraints is forbidden), I don't understand why this error pops up in my case.
I am trying the following code:
CREATE TABLE nations (
nations_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
name NVARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
continent NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
habitants_at_2024 INTEGER,
capital NVARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_nations PRIMARY KEY(nations_id),
CONSTRAINT unique_nation_name UNIQUE(name)
);
-- cities
CREATE TABLE cities(
cities_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
name NVARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
country NVARCHAR2(255),
CONSTRAINT pk_cities PRIMARY KEY(cities_id),
CONSTRAINT unique_city_name UNIQUE(name),
CONSTRAINT fk_country FOREIGN KEY(country) REFERENCES nations(name)
);
ALTER TABLE nations ADD CONSTRAINT fk_capital FOREIGN KEY(capital) REFERENCES cities(name);

The error message:

ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

pops up on the line with the ALTER TABLE statement.
However, I am quite sure there shouldn't be another constraint with the name fk_capital. To verify this, I tried the following as suggested in this question
SELECT *
  FROM all_constraints
 WHERE table_name = UPPER('table_name'); 

The command works fine, but I cannot find the constraint name in the resulting table either. What's more, I tried the following:
ALTER TABLE nations DROP CONSTRAINT fk_capital;
ALTER TABLE nations ADD CONSTRAINT fk_capital FOREIGN KEY(capital) REFERENCES cities(name);

The attempt to drop the constraint fails with the error message ORA-02443, which suggests there is no constraint with the name fk_capital. Right after that, ORA-02264 pops up again, indicating once more the name would already be in use. I made sure there is no typo - the code you're seeing is copy-pasted. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance for all answers!
PS.: I found another post suggesting that I can find the constraint-name using
SELECT owner, constraint_type, table_name
from user_constraints
where constraint_name = 'fk_capital';

but the resulting table is empty in my case.

The names in Oracle's data dictionary appear in uppercase. Instead of querying for fk_capital, you should query for FK_CAPITAL.
SELECT owner, constraint_type, table_name
FROM   user_constraints
WHERE  constraint_name = 'FK_CAPITAL';


Thank you! Using this, I found a table for testing I had forgotten to drop. This one used a constraint with the 'fk_capital'.
So, the constraint existed already, but not in the table 'nations'. And using upper-case was mandatory indeed. Thus, I could not drop it by Altering table 'nations', but it existed nevertheless.

When you execute queries to check for the constraint fk_capital, it may not return results because Oracle treats it as FK_CAPITAL internally.
Steps to Resolve the Issue:

Verify the Constraint Name: Run the following query to check for constraints in uppercase:

SELECT owner, constraint_type, table_name
FROM user_constraints
WHERE constraint_name = 'FK_CAPITAL';

Check All Constraints for the Table: If the above query doesn't work, list all constraints for the nations table to confirm its existence:

SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type
FROM user_constraints
WHERE table_name = UPPER('NATIONS');

Dropping the Constraint (If Necessary): If the fk_capital constraint exists, you can drop it using:

ALTER TABLE nations DROP CONSTRAINT fk_capital;

Recreate the Constraint: Once confirmed or dropped, you can recreate the constraint:

ALTER TABLE nations
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_capital FOREIGN KEY (capital) REFERENCES cities(name);
Additional Tips:
Ensure No Duplicate Constraints: Confirm that no other constraint is using the name fk_capital across different schemas.
SELECT owner, table_name, constraint_name
FROM all_constraints
WHERE constraint_name = 'FK_CAPITAL';
Schema Ownership: If you are working in a multi-schema environment, ensure you are querying the correct schema by prefixing the table name with the schema name (e.g., schema_name.nations).
If the issue persists, it might be related to the Oracle free version limitations or a database bug.

Thank you too.  Step 1 already solved my problem: It found me a table which I had already forgotten that it existed. This forgotten table had indeed used a constraint with that name. Dropping  this table made everything run normally again.
